# Recovering the TestCase category after accidently moving failed TestCases back to Active in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: testcase, microsoft-test-manager

I was having a ***FolderA*** created in a TestSuite under Microsoft Test Manager. Ran the TestCases one after another and now I have 15 TestCases **Failed** and 15 **Passed** and 15 Active, as category in the TestPlan.

Now, next day I got insane and moved my Passed and Failed TestCases back to Active, by Right click them and selecting "**Rest test to Active**".

So I **lost my last status** of one day work.

How can I move them all back again to Failed and Passed Category.?

Thanks & Regards
Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set them back to their previous status as if they had never been reset to active as TFS doesn't allow you to fake dates and/or remove history. However, if you look at the test run under Test >> Analyze Test Runs you should be able to see what the result of those tests were before you reset their status. You can then change the status of those tests back manually.